# Build with msbuild and dynamically set project references

Tags: msbuild, reference

I have a couple of projects which reference SQL Server assemblies. With SQL Server 2005 and SQL Server 2008 I am currently maintaining 2 project files which point to the same source files and the only difference is the references to the SQL Server assemblies.

Is there some way that I can only maintain one project and dynamically specify the references in my build script?

Comment: Don't the 2005 assemblies work against 2008?

Comment: No, but the 2008 assemblies do work against 2005. The only issue is that I release a couple of these projects on codeplex and I like to make a release for people that only have SQL 2005 and one for people that have 2008. Some of these assemblies are in the GAC so (as far as I am aware) I can't redistribute all my dependancies. And I'm not sure that I would want to bloat my release size even if I could.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Searching for a solution to the same problem you had I came to the proposed solution of having a Condition on the ItemGroup. But this had a side effect because in Visual Studio references I could see both references, which also impacted ReSharper.

I finally use a Choose When Otherwise and I don't have any issue anymore with ReSharper and Visual Studio showing two References.

```
<Choose>
  <When Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'client1DeployClickOnce' ">
    <ItemGroup>
        <ProjectReferenceInclude="..\client1\app.Controls\app.Controls.csproj">
        <Project>{A7714633-66D7-4099-A255-5A911DB7BED8}</Project>
        <Name>app.Controls %28Sources\client1\app.Controls%29</Name>
      </ProjectReference>
    </ItemGroup>
  </When>
  <Otherwise>
    <ItemGroup>
      <ProjectReference Include="..\app.Controls\app.Controls.csproj">
        <Project>{2E6D4065-E042-44B9-A569-FA1C36F1BDCE}</Project>
        <Name>app.Controls %28Sources\app.Controls%29</Name>
      </ProjectReference>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Otherwise>
</Choose>
```

You might read more about it on my blog post: [ProjectReference with Condition in your MSBuild project file][https://laurentkempe.com/2009/12/03/ProjectReference-with-Condition-in-your-MSBuild-project-files/]

Comment: Great solution Laurent, the duplicate references were annoying and this solution fixes that issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Every MSBuild element (*ok almost every*) can have a [Condition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7szfhaft.aspx) associated with it. What I would suggest is that you edit the project file (which is an MSBuild file itself) and place all the SQL server references in an ItemGroup which has a condition on it for instance:

```
  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(SqlServerTargetEdition)'=='2005'">
    <!-- SQL Server 2005 References here -->
    <Reference Include="..."/>
  </ItemGroup>
```

And another ItemGroup for Sql server 2008:

```
  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(SqlServerTargetEdition)'=='2008'">
    <!-- SQL Server 2008 References here -->
    <Reference Include="..."/>
  </ItemGroup>
```

You should provide a default value for the property SqlServerTargetEdition before those items are declared. Then at the command line you can override that value using the /p switch when invoking [msbuild.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx).

Sayed Ibrahim Hashimi

My Book: [Inside the Microsoft Build Engine : Using MSBuild and Team Foundation Build](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735626286)

Comment: Awesome Book! I have it and it saved my sanity!  Sayed, great to see you here on Stack Overflow!

Comment: This sounds like exactly what I am after. I will test this out at home tonight. Thanks Sayed!