# Choosing assembly to link against using configurations (MonoDevelop)

Tags: configuration, msbuild, monodevelop, .net-assembly

I'm working on a multiplatform game targeting Windows and Linux using the MonoGame project.  What I wanted to do was be able to build for either target using the same .csproj file, since the only thing that will change between the version is the referenced assemblies.  Specifically, I need to link against a different version of the MonoGame library depending on the target platform.  I looked around online, and it seems like this should be easy by editing the .csproj file.  So I did something like this:

```
<!-- System agnostic dependencies -->
<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
    ...

</ItemGroup>

<!-- Linux system dependencies -->
<ItemGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)'=='Linux' ">
  <Reference Include="MonoGame.Framework">
    <HintPath>..\Dependencies\Linux\MonoGame.Framework.dll</HintPath>
  </Reference>
</ItemGroup>

<!-- Windows system dependencies -->
<ItemGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)'=='Windows' ">
  <Reference Include="MonoGame.Framework.Windows">
    <HintPath>..\Dependencies\Windows\MonoGame.Framework.Windows.dll</HintPath>
  </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```

(Other dependencies omitted for brevity)

Well, this doesn't work at all.  I try to build under the Linux configuration and it immediately starts complaining that all the types contained within the MonoGame assembly's namespace are defined multiple times.  Obviously this is true, since there's two version of the assembly, but it was my understanding that with the conditions in the .csproj, it should only be trying to link against the appropriate version of the assembly.  I checked the output directory, and it even went ahead and copied all the dependencies for either configuration into the output.  So obviously I'm doing something wrong here.

The online documentation I found indicates that MonoDevelop has at least some support for MSBuild conditional statements, but I couldn't find anything more specific.  Either what I'm trying to do is not supported at all by MonoDevelop or I'm doing something really dumb.

I figured if what I'm trying to do is not supported, I could always recompile the Windows version of MonoGame to use a different namespace and do something hack-y like:

```
#ifdef __WINDOWS_VERSION__
#define Microsoft.Xna Microsoft.XnaWindowsVersion
#endif
```

...but then again, that seems sinful.  Any ideas about how I should go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under standard MSBuild you would solve this using a `<choose>` element:

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1836417/736079

Comment: I cannot check right now whether Mono adheres to this, but I suspect it will.

Comment: MsBuild alsp evaluates other conditionals in different ways. Your current solution would lead to multiple references in Visua Studio, but it would build.

Comment: Thank you.  I had actually tried this before with the same results.  An hour ago I discovered that there's a checkbox you have to tick in the solution settings to even enable MSBuild, so I felt like a big idiot when I figured this out.  Now it builds, except for one assembly that isn't getting copied right.  Still, the multiple references are now making additional coding extremely obnoxious; off the top of your head do you know if there's a way to resolve the ambiguity while leaving both assemblies referenced (this probably warrants its own question, but I thought I'd leave it here).

Comment: You can use multiple projects and in Visual Studio I'd leverage the "Add as Link" feature to share sources between projects... It's still messy, but works.

Comment: That is messy, but I may have no other option.  Marking this as the correct answer.